# Why am I not able to delete a cookie using Cookie.js?

Tags: javascript, cookies, js-cookie

I'm using [Jscookie.js](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)
I'm passing down a cookie (on the header) on the response from my server.
I can see using cookiemanager+ that the client receives the cookie. My JavaScript attempts to delete the cookie, but the cookie is not being deleted.

Oddly enough, **when I run the project locally the cookie is deleted** successfully, but when I deploy to my test server the cookie does not get deleted.

My server code:

```
var DownloadToken = request.Headers.GetCookies(UploadToken").FirstOrDefault();
                if (DownloadToken != null)
                {
                    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("DownloadToken", DownloadToken["UploadToken"].Value.ToString());  //create a new cookie
                    cookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(6.0); //expire cookie in 6 minutes
                    cookie.Domain = request.RequestUri.Host == "localhost" ? null : request.RequestUri.Host;
                    cookie.Path = "/";
                    response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] {cookie});
                }

return response;
```

MY client code:

```
Cookies.remove('DownloadToken'); //clears this cookie value for fileDownloadToken
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server my cookie.domain was being set, so when I tried to remove the cookie on the client after it was passed down it would not work, because in order to remove the cookie I had to specify the domain.

For example, I updated my server code that creates the cookie, so it adds the domain. Also updated client code that removes the cookie to specify the domain when removing the cooke:

On server:

```
var DownloadToken = request.Headers.GetCookies(UploadToken").FirstOrDefault();
                if (DownloadToken != null)
                {
                    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("DownloadToken", DownloadToken["UploadToken"].Value.ToString());  //create a new cookie
                    cookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(6.0); //expire cookie in 6 minutes
                    cookie.Domain = request.RequestUri.Host == "localhost" ? null : ".mywebsite.com";
                    cookie.Path = "/";
                    response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] {cookie});
                }

return response;
```

and on client:

```
Cookies.remove('DownloadToken', { domain: '.mywebsite.com' });
```